# Can the RBS migrate command in PS be targeted at a document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rbs, migrate

I've got RBS configured and working in our dev environment, but now I face the task of migrating about 1.5TB of existing content into the RBS blobstore.

Instructions for migrating content to the blobstore can be found on the internet, no problem there, but the command always targets the content database like so:

[image]

I tried this initially, but there's so much content to migrate it takes DAYS to finish (in my case, I ran out of drive space after five days).

**Is it possible to migrate files from only a single document library or subsite instead of the entire content database?** If not, can users still use the site & files normally while the migrate process is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too much data to migrate into Microsoft's implementation of RBS, which has a [limitation of 200GB for content databases.](http://limitation%20of%20200GB%20for%20content%20databases) Microsoft's RBS solution was designed for those moving from Windows Internal Database on WSSv3 to SharePoint 2010 utilizing SQL Express. It was not designed around the usage scenario of those using SQL Standard or Enterprise.

If you're set on using RBS, look at a 3rd party solution instead.

It is not possible to target RBS at a narrower scope than the content database.